# Configure VirtualHost to Rewrite HTTP://subdomain... to HTTPS://internaldirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, rewrite, https

How do I configure Apache to rewrite an http request for a subdomain to an https request for the correct directory?

For example, I have the following VirtualHost configuration:

[image: virtualhost with rewrite]

However, this turns `http://redmine...us` into `https://redmine...us/redmine`.

Also, changing

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/redmine [R]` to

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R]`

seems to simply redirect the HTTP request to `HTTP://...us`, which is currently the default `/var/www/index.html` page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why the screenshot and not a pasted config? And you can use example.com/net/org in your examples http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-apache-force-https-secure-connections.html

Comment: The rewrite did not work, but I used a redirect like in the link you provided that is redirecting all `http://redmine.example.us` requests to `https://redmine.example.us` at the appropriate directory, and I added a virtualhost config in my `default-ssl` file that references ServerName redmine.example.us to the DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine.  However, I am having a new issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/447600/redmine-virtualhost-config-not-working-with-document-root